# Convert multiple rows into one column for a specific start of row name starting

Tags: r

From a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(row_name = c("sha1", "sha2", "edt1", "edt2", "perform1", "perform2"),
                 value = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60))
```

How is it possible to convert rows to columns to receive this result?

```
df <- data.frame(sha = c(10, 20), edt = c(30, 40), perform = c(50, 60))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it first by separating the number from the words that you want to be the variable names.  Then you can `pivot_wider()` on the names and then remove the variable that captured the number.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(row_name = c("sha1", "sha2", "edt1", "edt2", "perform1", "perform2"),
                 value = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60))
df %>% 
  separate_wider_regex(row_name, c(name = "[^\\d]*", obs = "\\d")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value") %>% 
  select(-obs)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>     sha   edt perform
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1    10    30      50
#> 2    20    40      60
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```
data.frame(split(x = df$value, f = gsub("\\d", "", df$row_name)))

  edt perform sha
1  30      50  10
2  40      60  20
```